# Откуда скрипты Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, dom, nuxt.js

Всем привет, подскажите как понять откуда в DOM эти скрипты? Может это какие то плагины
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это вэбпак собирает 2гига ваших node_modules в 15 мегабайт эту лапшу нарезает на кусочки для удобной передачи.

Включи анализ чтоб посмотерь что там внутри https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#analyze

Comment: просто pageSpeed ругается на один из файлов, это получается плагин какой-то скорее всего?

Comment: не только плагин может быть, полезную ссылку добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Comment: 15 Мб, бррр. Я тут насмерть воюю с жирнейшим бандлом в 2 мб. P. S. node_modules 86 МБ))) Средний реальный проект

Comment: @Alexander  а я писал сайты для wap...  10кило уже не загружалось в лыжи